# 400 Not Found wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I moved wordpress site into Amazon EC2 Linux server.i installed apache and other all things for run wordpress. and point the domain. now homepage is working well. but when i'm going to sub pages like (http://fibarozwaveshop.com/contact/)  i got 404 Not Found Error. but if i change worpdress permalink into default. sub pages are showing well. and .htaccess file is correct. also Mod_rewrite module is activated. can anyone tell me what is the problem is? i can pay you.

All info about server - http://fibarozwaveshop.com/info.php/

Thanks.

Comment: Switch back to default theme and then check inner pages are working or not..

Comment: try: 
1. disable "W3 Total Cache" plugin
2. set permalinks to default
3. again set permalink to custom
check now inner pages working or not

Comment: Check your .htaccess file permissions. is it writable or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please update your permalink from wordpress admin setting.**

**Setting->Permalinks**

Comment: this answer is useful for someone.